# Heroku Application Error. Error codes: 503 and H10. Error connecting to database

Tags: node.js, database, heroku, process, environment-variables

I am running a react/redux front end and a sequelize/express backend. Everything works on my local system AND this app did successfully launch in Heroku until a couple days ago (or at least that's when I noticed it). Now I just get the "Application Error" screen when I try to open it.

From when I push the build to Heroku until the crash, these are the heroku logs:

```
2021-05-26T15:35:39.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-05-26T15:35:42.783549+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-05-26T15:35:47.633470+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-05-26T15:35:47.633500+00:00 app[web.1]: > instagram-clone@1.0.0 start /app
2021-05-26T15:35:47.633501+00:00 app[web.1]: > per-env
2021-05-26T15:35:47.633501+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-05-26T15:35:49.560858+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-05-26T15:35:49.560886+00:00 app[web.1]: > instagram-clone@1.0.0 start:production /app
2021-05-26T15:35:49.560887+00:00 app[web.1]: > node ./bin/www
2021-05-26T15:35:49.560887+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-05-26T15:35:51.608929+00:00 app[web.1]: Error connecting to database
2021-05-26T15:35:51.734352+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2021-05-26T15:35:51.915636+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-05-26T15:35:51.919374+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-05-26T15:35:56.986578+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-05-26T15:36:02.109257+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-05-26T15:36:02.109287+00:00 app[web.1]: > instagram-clone@1.0.0 start /app
2021-05-26T15:36:02.109288+00:00 app[web.1]: > per-env
2021-05-26T15:36:02.109288+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-05-26T15:36:04.147834+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-05-26T15:36:04.147883+00:00 app[web.1]: > instagram-clone@1.0.0 start:production /app
2021-05-26T15:36:04.147884+00:00 app[web.1]: > node ./bin/www
2021-05-26T15:36:04.147885+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-05-26T15:36:08.145690+00:00 app[web.1]: Error connecting to database
2021-05-26T15:36:08.323027+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2021-05-26T15:36:08.387353+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-05-26T15:36:09.412740+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=instagram51820.herokuapp.com request_id=84269189-4bb5-4c66-a474-69e7e2be0e5c fwd="73.80.9.120" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-26T15:36:09.529024+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=instagram51820.herokuapp.com request_id=5df8d7e0-c19d-4fa3-8380-67e0d63121e8 fwd="73.80.9.120" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

In my config index.js file I have the environment set up as:

```
environment: process.env.NODE_ENV || "development",
```

When I do the build, heroku does recognize that is now production.

I have been all over and cannot seem to figure out what is wrong/what happened. Any help at all would be sincerely apprectiated.

Comment: Have you hard coded any `port` in your in your code?

Comment: Nah, I set up a proxy for the front end to hit (localhost:5000) but that's it.